# Bash script $variable content echoing empty

Tags: shell-script, curl, variable

$RESPONSE variable does not being displayed in if block. 
In my code i have commented exactly where

```
#!/bin/bash

TIME=`date +%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M:%S`
cat sites.txt | while read site
do
    URL="http://$site"
    RESPONSE=`curl -I $URL | head -n1`
    echo $RESPONSE #echo works
    if echo $RESPONSE | grep -E '200 OK|302 Moved|302 Found' > /dev/null;then
        echo "$URL is up"
    else
        #$RESPONSE variable empty. Returns [TIME] [URL] is DOWN. Status:
        echo "[$TIME] $URL is DOWN. Status:$RESPONSE" | bash slackpost.sh
    fi  
done
```

Any ideas how to pipe $RESPONSE text with?
$RESPONSE holds string like curl: (6) Could not resolvehost ..... or HTTP.1.1 200 OK

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/272265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script actually works. Are you sure your `sites.txt` is correct? For example, I tried with:

```
$ cat sites.txt 
google.com
unix.stackexchange.com
yahoo.com
```

I saved your script as `foo.sh`, and running it on the file above gives:

```
$ foo.sh 2>/dev/null
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
http://google.com is up
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
http://unix.stackexchange.com is up
HTTP/1.1 301 Redirect
[10-03-2017:20:49:29] http://yahoo.com is DOWN. Status:HTTP/1.1 301 Redirect
```

By the way, as you can see above, it fails for yahoo.com which is redirecting. Perhaps a better way would be to use ping to check. Something like this (including some other general improvements):

```
while read site
do
    if ping -c1 -q "$site" &>/dev/null; then
        echo "$site is up"
    else
        echo "[$(date +%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M:%S)] $site is not reachable."
    fi  
done < sites.txt
```

If you really do need the status, use:

```
#!/bin/bash

## No need for cat, while can take a file as input
while read site
do
    ## Try not to use UPPER CASE variables to avoid conflicts
    ## with the default environmental variable names. 
    site="http://$site";
    response=$(curl -I "$site" 2>/dev/null | head -n1)
    ## grep -q is silent
    if grep -qE '200 OK|302 Moved|302 Found|301 Redirect' <<<"$response"; then
        echo "$site is up"
    else
        ## better to run 'date' on the fly, if you do it once
        ## at the beginning, the time shown might be very different.
        echo "[$(date +%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M:%S)] $site is DOWN. Status:$response" 
    fi  
done < sites.txt
```

Comment: Hmmm strange.Can it be then rasberry pi issue? maybe bash does not read it somehow?

Comment: anyway your solution is way better with ping at it works as expected

Comment: @Mindau are you 100% sure you're actually using bash? You didn't mention anything about raspberry. Are you sure you aren't using `sh` instead of bash, or even some sort of busybox shell?